# How to calculate the progress text during animation?

Tags: javascript, css

I display a [circle progress with svg](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-5ghp3y?file=index.ts). I can't figure out the calculation of the percentages of the progress.

The value is 60. so I need to display in text (or in the console, it's no matters) the percentages while the circle is fills up. 1%, 2%, ... 60%.

So I try to do:

```
let updates = 0;

    anime({
      ...
      update:(anim) => {
       updates++;
       console.log({ updates });
      }
    });
```

But it comeout: `1,2,3,4...231,232,233..` - which make no sense for me those numbers and the way to calculate the percentages.

I also try to do:

```
    anime({
      ...
      update:(anim) => {
       console.log({ c: Math.round(anime.progress) });
      }
    });
```

But its comeout: `9, 9, 14, 23, ... , 99, 99, 99, 100, 100, 100`

So what calculate method I should to use to display 1%, 2% .. 60% during the animation?

[stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-5ghp3y?file=index.ts)

Comment: are you able to identify the minimum and maximum number? if yes, then you could just use ((progress - min) / (max - min)) * 100%

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval and start with anime. Anime works each 100 duration as a point

```
let myVar=setInterval(myTimer, 100);
let index=0;
function myTimer() {
   if(index<value){ index++;
      textCounter.innerHTML=index+"%";
      return;
   }
   myStopFunction(); 
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
```